# How to use compiler #warning in my code?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, gcc, warnings

I am writing a larger project and am trying to make a deprecated method "print" a #warning about the deprecation when the method is called.

How could I do so? Just again: I have this

```
#warning -methodname:(id)sender is deprecated, use ...
```

I only want this message appear in the build warnings, if the message is called, not all the time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I flag a method as deprecated in Objective-C 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908715/how-do-i-flag-a-method-as-deprecated-in-objective-c-2-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this after the declaration of the method, before the semicolon: `__attribute__((__deprecated__))`

Comment: Thanks, worked fine. Can I also put an additional message in the warning, e.g. "use ... instead"?

Comment: Some versions of GCC support a string parameter on this attribute, but I don't recall which. The syntax would be: `__attribute__((__deprecated__("foobar!")))`