# Objective-C: How to prevent a non-default initializer from being called?

Tags: objective-c, initializer

I have created a different init method and would like that to be the designated initializer instead of the standard `-init`.  How can I prevent client code from instantiating the class using `-init`?

e.g.

```
/* everyone must call this */
- (id)initWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
      _info = info;
  }

  return self;
}

/* Don't want anyone to be able to create this using init */
```

Comment: sidenote: your method is missing `return self;`

Comment: and it's "designated initializer", not "default initializer".

Comment: Either map `init` to another `init...` or make it throw an error.  There's no way to "hide" it.

Comment: How about leave the `init` alone and mention in your documentation how the object should be initialized?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way of preventing other programmers from calling -init](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634256/best-way-of-preventing-other-programmers-from-calling-init) or [Is it possible to make the -init method private in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195078/is-it-possible-to-make-the-init-method-private-in-objective-c?lq=1)

Answer (score 5):

`init` comes from the hierarchy of `NSObject`. Every class will have `init`.

Hence **you can't** remove the method of super-class.

Also user / developer can use any other way to create a new object like `new`, `initWith...`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
- (id)init 
{
  return [self initWithInfo:@{}];
}

- (id)initWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) 
  {
      _info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:info];
  }
  return self;
}
```

Comment: How you pass data to someDictionary??? Before allocation of class?

Comment: All the idea of the question is initializing the object with a custom dictionary and you are setting it to `nil`.

Comment: This approach is good when you have to do some custom initializations, but in order to initialize info dictionary, must be called `initWithInfo` method. There is nothing to be sent by calling `init` method.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't remove superclass initializers, you can "block" them by overriding them like this:

```
- (id)init
{
    NSAssert(NO, @"Use the designated initializer: -initWithInfo:");
    [self doesNotRecognizeSelector: _cmd];
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self = nil;
    }
    return self;
}
```

This will at least "fail fast" (at runtime.) It'd be nice if this could be made to fail at compile time, but I don't believe there's any way to achieve that at this point.

Comment: Why call `[super init]` at all?

Comment: I guess you probably don't *need* to.

Comment: And if it fails, the assert won't fire.  It makes no sense.  It's "fail fairly fast".

Comment: Just for you, I'll move the assert outside the conditional. The important part of the sauce here is `-doesNotRecognizeSelector:`

Comment: Do it for all of mankind, or even just yourself.  Don't worry about me as I won't use the code.

Comment: Oh, hey neat. There is a compile-time way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9634366/438982

Comment: Yeah much better.  Mark the question as a dupe then.

Comment: Consider it so marked.